# Insert into tables linked by primary key

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, insert

I have two tables with the relationship

```
+----------------------+      +-----------------+
|        Shape         |      |  Point_Values   |
+----------------------+      +-----------------+
| shape_id (KEY)       |      | id (KEY)        |
| shape_name (VARCHAR) |      | point_x (INT)   |
+----------------------+      | point_y (INT)   |
                              | shape_id (INT)  |
                              +-----------------+
```

How do you go about structuring an insert in general or for CodeIgniter at the same time where you get the shape and points in the same request, meaning that when a shape finishes there is an array of points and the shape name/id.  I have to do the inserts into the table but have the shape_id in both match.

---

By request

```
Array
(
    [name] => "circle"
    [points] => Array
        (
            [x] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 182
                    [1] => 190
                    [2] => 215
                    [3] => 240
                    [4] => 291
                    [5] => 328
                    [6] => 364
                    [7] => 391
                    [8] => 425
                    [9] => 459
                    [10] => 487
                    [11] => 512
                    [12] => 529
                    [13] => 540
                    [14] => 551
                    [15] => 560
                    [16] => 570
                    [17] => 581
                    [18] => 592
                    [19] => 604
                    [20] => 617
                    [21] => 628
                    [22] => 635
                    [23] => 639
                    [24] => 642
                    [25] => 642
                    [26] => 640
                    [27] => 630
                    [28] => 619
                    [29] => 606
                    [30] => 591
                )

            [y] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 165
                    [1] => 159
                    [2] => 150
                    [3] => 147
                    [4] => 144
                    [5] => 144
                    [6] => 147
                    [7] => 152
                    [8] => 162
                    [9] => 172
                    [10] => 184
                    [11] => 199
                    [12] => 211
                    [13] => 219
                    [14] => 225
                    [15] => 228
                    [16] => 231
                    [17] => 232
                    [18] => 233
                    [19] => 233
                    [20] => 231
                    [21] => 222
                    [22] => 204
                    [23] => 189
                    [24] => 156
                    [25] => 133
                    [26] => 120
                    [27] => 100
                    [28] => 85
                    [29] => 69
                    [30] => 54
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: will u show the array u have??

Comment: @diEcho added to the question. That array is then parsed into the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well considering that array, this code should work nicely. It does one initial insert to get the id from table shape and all points are batch inserted.

```
function insertShape($s){
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO shape (name) VALUES ("'.$s['name'].'");');
    $id=mysql_insert_id();
    $i=0;
    for(;;){
        if(!isset($s['points']['x'][$i], $s['points']['y'][$i]))break;
        $inserts[]='('.$id.','.$s['points']['x'][$i].','.$s['points']['y'][$i].')';
        $i++;
    }
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO point_values (shape_id,x,y) VALUES '.implode(',',$inserts));
}
```

I'd probably make that for into a foreach if your situation doesn't need rigorous testing on the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u basic Algorithm, first u make foreign key constraint between `shape_id(point_value)` and `shape_id(shape)`

first insert into shape table

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO shape SET shape_name='".$array['name']."'");
```

and then get the **last_insert_id**

```
$shape_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

then go to point_value table

```
foreach( $array['points] as $k)
{

   $qry= "INSERT INTO point_value SET
                               point_x=(int)$array['points']['x'][$i],
                               point_y=(int)$array['points']['y'][$i],
                               shape_id=(int)$shape_id ";
   mysql_query($qry);
}
```

i hope this will help u..ask for help
Thanks

Comment: you can batch insert all the points, no need to spam the server with more than 2 requests.

Comment: @khez even your query also request two times. if we want to insert into two tables then we must need to call server 2 times( AFAIK)

Comment: exactly, 2 times. Exactly 2 times. You do it 31 times. 1 for shape and 30 for points. Considering the circle shape example.